# Strapi AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Deploy success but cannot access URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, strapi

I'm trying to deploy Strapi 4 to AWS elastic beanstalk.

After deploying, the app is not accessible by the URL (e.g http://lrd-api.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com).

The instance is running, and docker logs show a successful deployment. The Strapi app is running and connected to the RDS database, but I am unable to access it through the URL.

Are there any additional steps I'm unaware of?

My server.ts file (config/server.ts for Strapi)

```
import cronTasks from './functions/cron_tasks';

export default ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  app: {
    keys: env.array('APP_KEYS'),
  },
  webhooks: {
    populateRelations: env.bool('WEBHOOKS_POPULATE_RELATIONS', false),
  },
  cron: {
    enabled: true,
    tasks: cronTasks,
  },
});
```

I have tried changing the EB to a load balanced instance to listen to both ports 80 and 433.

Comment: To clarify further. I have an ENV file that populates HOST & PORT variables
HOST is set to 0.0.0.0 and PORT is set to 1337 (as seen above)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this same issue, this was the problem:

- Elastic beanstalk load balance was listening to port 80 for the instance port 80
- The app itself was on port 1337

To make it work, what I did was:

- Change the port mapping in my docker-compose.yml
- Instead of port 1337:1337, I used 80:1337